# Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1917 (note 1 of 2)

Tags: identificación-de-término

For the year 1917 in my great-grandfathers Civil Guard records there are two entries.

Here is the first note:
[image]
The transcribed text:

> El Excmo. Sr. [Señor] Director Gral. [General] del Cuerpo en comon
> [comunicación] del 2º xxx noº 235 [?] fecha 10 de Julio se dignó dar
> las gracias a este indº [individuo] por el distinguido comportamiento
> observado con motivo de las inxxxciones xxx en la provincia de Sevilla
> xxx de Marzo del año actual.
>
> El Comandante Mayor

I have tried to work out the abbreviations based on the previous notes completed so I think I have been able to detect mode of the words. I am not sure of the exact abbreviation for **comunicación**, but it does look like **comon** to me.

I am not sure of the *number* that is referred to either. I think it might be **235**.

---

#### Translation

Translation based on the answer:

> The Excellency Sir Director General of the Corps in communication of
> the 2nd negotiation nº 235 [?] dated 10 July deigned to thank this
> individual for the distinguished behaviour observed on the occasion of
> the floods that occurred in the province of Seville in the month of
> March of the current year.
>
> The Major Commander

I might be wrong, but I found these resources about the floods:

1. PDF document: [El estudio de las inundaciones históricas  en Sevilla a través de fuentes periodísticas (siglo XX)](http://file:///C:/Users/ajtru/AppData/Local/Temp/67297-Texto%20del%20art%C3%ADculo-4564456578798-1-10-20200129.pdf)
2. Web article: [La gran riada](https://www.diariodejerez.es/jerez/gran-riada_0_1116788491.html).

---

### Related Questions

- [Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1917 (note 2 of 2)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39489/28260)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestions

> El Excmo. Sr. [Señor] Director Gral. [General] del Cuerpo en comon
> [comunicación] del 2º **Negociado** nº 235 [?] fecha 10 de Julio se dignó dar
> las gracias a este indº [individuo] por el distinguido comportamiento
> observado con motivo de las **inundaciones ocurridas** en la provincia de Sevilla
> **en el mes** de Marzo del año actual.
>
> El Comandante Mayor

---

According to the Oxford Dictionary

> [deign](https://www.lexico.com/definition/deign)
>
> 1.1 **archaic** with object 
> **Condescend** to give (something) ‘he had deigned an apology’
> [condescend](https://www.lexico.com/definition/condescend)
> 1.1 with infinitive
>  **Do something** in such a way as **to** **emphasize** that one clearly regards it as below one's dignity or level of importance.

If you don't like deign you can use condescend instead, they are marked as synonyms in the Collins Dictionary.

It's not used in a negative way in the original text but to **emphasize** that the Director General **is doing** a **huge favor** to your ancestor. That rank is the highest one in the Guardia Civil. Such person is usually busy with very important things like having a cup of tea with the King or the Prime Minister or whatever that he did. Instead of doing such things, he's wasting his precious time congratulating a simple guard.

It's used to remark the distance in the organization or in society between two persons and how gracious is the first one doing something in favor of the second one.

Hope that helps you to understand the sentence.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have updated the question with the English translation and attempted to find information about these floods.

Comment: I am confused by the translated word **deigned**. I say this because if you look here https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/deign it says: *If you say that someone deigned to do something, you are expressing your disapproval of the fact that they did it unwillingly, because they thought they were too important to do it.*. Is that really what the note is implying?

Comment: I am more confused now. When I look here https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/digno it refers to *digno* in a positive light wheras *deigned* has more of a negative meaning.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle I have updated my answer trying to explain the use of deign.

Comment: Thanks. I get the import of the context now.